# Consecutive number using a textbox ( VBA )

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

The problem i got the textbox give orden to another textbox be a consecutive number. example

This is my userform

```
(Textbox1 ) (TextBox2)
Product:     Number:
Door car    4
```

And this is my excel sheets:

```
Product:    Number:
Door Car    1
Door Car    2
Door Car    3
Door Car    4
```

Thanks, and sorry for my English..

Comment: This is unclear what exactly you want to ask. Please update your OP with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Following Codes

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    If Not IsNull(Me.TextBox2) Then
        For i = 1 To Val(Me.TextBox2)
            sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.TextBox1
            sht.Cells(i + 1, 2) = i
        Next i
    End If

Set sht = Nothing
End Sub
```

> ## Edit:For last row entry try following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lasRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lasRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    If Not IsNull(Me.TextBox4) Then
        For i = 1 To Val(Me.TextBox4)
            sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Me.TextBox4
            sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Me.ComboBox5
        Next i
    End If

Set sht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  I got one more dude if i got for example a textbox 2 and combobox 2 how i can used multiple textbox and combobox and make te consecutive number.

Comment: If I am using 4 textbox,, my question is how to use the code you gave me. And aside, look for the next consecutive empty row.

Comment: I got conflict when im using the same column i tried with a last row code, but how i can apply with your code.
    

    LastRow = sht.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row
    sht.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox5.Text
    sht.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = TextBox4.Text`

Comment: @LuisBlancasWong See edited part of answer as per your comment.

Comment: Hello i got a dude i used your code and work fine, but i dont have the consecutive for example if i put 2 then repeat the number writed in the textbox, tried serching but i dont find something similar. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisBlancasWong Still you are facing the issue?